# Duplicating and printing Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

The goal of this program is to read files that contains integers from 1 to 100000 and then perform an insertion sort and a quicksort. The first file i'm reading contains integers 1 to 100000 in ascending order. The issue that I'm having currently is that when trying to print an array containing the integers; it will print repeatedly before finishing. For example, when running the program, it prints the array several times before stopping and also prevents me from scrolling up further. Also when scrolling to the side in the console. the bottom array gets messed up. I'm using eclipse as my IDE:

Before scrolling to the side:
[image]

After scrolling to the side
[image]

I'm stumped as to why this is occurring. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
public class Program {

public static void insertionSort(int[] a){
    for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i++){
        int temp = a[i];
        int j;
        for (j = i -1; j >= 0 && temp < a[j]; j--){
            a[j+1] = a[j];
        }
        a[j+1] = temp;
    }
}

public static int n = 100000;
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file to open");
    String fileName = in.nextLine();
    File file = new File(fileName);
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
    int[] original = new int[n];
    int count = 0;
    while(reader.hasNextInt()){
        original[count] = reader.nextInt();
        count++;
    }
    in.close();
    reader.close();
    int duplicate[] = new int[original.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < original.length; i++){
        duplicate[i] = original[i];
    }
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    insertionSort(duplicate);
    long estimatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    System.out.println("Function took " + estimatedTime +"ms");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(duplicate));
}
```

}

Comment: [Arrays.copyOfRange()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int[],%20int,%20int))

Comment: It's extremely unclear what the issue is that you're trying to describe ("it will print repeatedly"). Please be more specific about what is not printing correctly.

Comment: What does this **question** has to do with [tag:sorting]?

Comment: In your insertionSort method you should probably iterate until 'i <= n'. Currently it is only 'i < n'

Comment: @KuramaYoko It will get out of bounds and crash.

Comment: @KuramaYoko: that would result in an [`IndexOutOfBounds`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) exception.

Comment: Oh I see now 'int key = array[i];' My bad.

Comment: You may want to consider writing the output to a file instead of the console. That would resolve the issue you described about 'preventing you from scrolling up.' The console is limited in the number of characters it can display.